# How can i generate new wallet address using cardano-wallet cli and cardano wallet api after created my wallet?

Tags: wallet, cardano-cli, cardano-node, api

yoroi and daedalus provide UI to generate new wallet address, how can i use cardano-wallet cli and cardano rest api to generate new address?

Answer (score 3):

Once you have your `cardano-wallet` runnig, you can create a new wallet using CLI with the following command:

```
$ cardano-wallet wallet create from-recovery-phrase "My Wallet"
Please enter a 15–24 word recovery-phrase sentence: <enter generated recovery-phrase words here>
(Enter a blank line if you do not wish to use a second factor.)
Please enter a 9–12 word recovery-phrase second factor: <skip or enter new recovery-phrase words here>
Please enter a passphrase: ****************
Enter the passphrase a second time: ****************
$
```

See [more `cardano-wallet` cli commands](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-wallet/wiki/Wallet-command-line-interface#wallet-create-from-recovery-phrase).

---

To create a new wallet using `cardano-wallet` REST API, you can use the following command:

```
$ curl -vX POST http://localhost:8090/v2/wallets \
   -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
   -d '{
        "name": "Shelley",
        "mnemonic_sentence": ["identify", "screen", "lock", "bargain", "inch", "drop", "canyon", "flock", "dry", "zone", "wash", "argue", "system", "glory", "light"],
        "passphrase": "Secure Passphrase",
        "address_pool_gap": 20
        }'
```

See [REST API documentation](https://input-output-hk.github.io/cardano-wallet/api/edge/#operation/postWallet) for more information about this call.

Comment: I know how to create wallet, I have already read the documentation. I want to know how to generate new address when you created your own wallet, there is 20 address in your wallet after created, I want to generate more.

Comment: This is what `address_pool_gap` is for, you can specify more than 20 address, but be careful!  Using values other than 20 automatically makes your wallet invalid with regards to BIP-44 address discovery (https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0044.mediawiki). It means that you will not be able to fully restore your wallet in a different software which is strictly following BIP-44.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like that?

```
# generate keys
cardano-cli address key-gen --verification-key-file payment.vkey --signing-key-file payment.skey
# build address from pubkey
cardano-cli address build --payment-verification-key-file payment.vkey --out-file payment.addr --mainnet
```

Comment: yeah, but instead of using cardano-cli, i'm using cardano-wallet cli and wallet backend restful api.